# Jquery / Ajax success data list when displayed "undefined"

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a ajax code. This code taking a list from controller. But im taking "undefined" message when i display this.

Ajax

```
           $.ajax(
           {
               url: "/Panel/OpenOrderDetail1",
               type: 'GET',
               data: { id: id},
               dataType: 'json',
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               success: function (data) {
                       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                           satir += "<span>" + data[i].ProductId+ "</span><br>";
                       }
                   }
               },
           });
```

Controller (.net core)

```
[HttpGet]
       public JsonResult OpenOrderDetail1(int id)
       {
           // some codes....
           List<OrderDetailViewModel> orderList = new List<OrderDetailViewModel>();
           foreach (DataRow item in data.Rows)
           {
               OrderDetailViewModel ovm = new OrderDetailViewModel();
               //listing .........................
               orderList.Add(ovm);
           }
           return Json(orderList);
       }
```

AND my class

```
public class OrderDetailViewModel
   {
       public decimal OrderId { get; set; }
       public string ProductCode { get; set; }
       public string? ProductName { get; set; }
       public decimal? OrderPrice { get; set; }
       public decimal? OrderAmount { get; set; }
       public decimal? OrderFPD { get; set; }
       public decimal? OrderKPD { get; set; }
       public decimal? OrderTotal { get; set; }
       public string? ProductExp { get; set; }
       public string? FinanceExp { get; set; }
       public decimal ProductId { get; set; }
       public decimal OrderLineId { get; set; }
   }
```

**NOT  : I can get the values. This is exact information. But I am getting "undefined" when listing.**

Comment: Try to change `ProductId` to `productId`

Comment: Please console your data so you can get an idea of why it's undefined `console.log(data)`

Answer (score 1):

You need change your code

```
satir += "<span>" + data[i].ProductId+ "</span><br>";
```

to

```
satir += "<span>" + data[i].productId+ "</span><br>";
```